# sql for find out a value from json_encided column in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I have a column of json_encoded in my table and want to check a value exist or not in that column. What type of query should write?

Example: I have a column in which values are: ["1","2","3","4"]  and  I want to check through query that 1 exists or not.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? If you have not then attempt at a solution if faced with a problem research the solution. If you don't find your solution then post the question with attempted code.

Comment: How to apply where query fro this column ?

Comment: @Anurag Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE Column LIKE '%"1"%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Sql Query :

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(fieldName, '["valueTobeChecked"]');
```

Assumptions: The data type of field should be "json"

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON_CONTAINS()` function accepts the `JSON` document being searched and another to compare against. It returns 1 when a match is found,

```
SELECT * FROM `book` 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(Field, '["values"]');
```